# Running wineConsole err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong fon

Tags: wine, fonts

I am trying to use the program Apophysis and am having some trouble. I installed and ran the program with wine and that all worked great. After setting some parameters the program generates a data file and a bat file which when run renders the data file into an image. Unfortunately when I run `wineconsole render.bat` I get the following error.

```
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
```

I have discovered that the error has nothing to do with apophysis or the particular bat file as when I run `wineconsole ""` I get the same error with additional information.

```
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
err:wineconsole:WCUSER_SetFont wrong font
wineconsole: Starting program "\"\"" failed.
The command is invalid.
```

I found one answer [here](http://comp.emulators.ms-windows.wine.narkive.com/LMcwst0Z/the-decent-font-error-deserves-to-be-a-faq) unfortunatly setting my $LANG didn't change any of my results. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it is as follows: After exporting a .flame it could be rendered by opening a terminal in the `/home/kevin/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Apophysis 2.0` running `wineconsole cmd` to get a mock power shell and then running `render.bat` in the power shell.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you could try to fix errors with wineconsole.exe

Here is the documentation for it
https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/cui-programs

Have you tried running your batch file via wine

```
wine render.bat
```

or with the user backend instead of the console backend

```
wine -- --backend=user render.bat
```

I get those errors running cmd.exe (the windows command enterpreter) via wine (i am using 16.04) and they don't seem to be fatal and i don't see any font issues.

Comment: This produces the behavior described in the question.